# Why does Phaser's setText() cause a CSS warning "Expected color but found '0'."?

Tags: javascript, css, text, warnings, phaser-framework

Title explains it. Here is the code for creating my text object:

```
statusBarHP.text = game.add.text(0, 0, '', {
    font:"16px Arial",
    fill:"#ffffff",
    stroke:"#000000",
    strokeThickness:2
});
```

Code for the object which holds the text:

```
statusBarHP = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'status-bar-red');
```

Code I use to change the text in the update function:

```
statusBarHP.text.setText(Math.floor(player.health) + '/' + player.max_health);
```

This happens every time I use setText(). I tried setting the fill and stroke to "rgb(255, 255, 255)" and "rgb(0, 0, 0)" and the color was correct, but I still got the warning...

Comment: In Chrome current and Phaser 2.4.4 I can't replicate this. What's your setup/environment? Where are you seeing this CSS error?

Comment: I don't seem to get the error in Chrome too. I mainly use Firefox (43.0.4) and I get it there.

Comment: Just downloaded and installed Firefox 44.0 and I'm not getting this error. Can you edit your question to include your creation of `statusBarHP`? For testing purposes, I'm using `var statusBarHP = { text: '' };`. And Phaser 2.4.4, right?

Comment: I edited it. I basically attach the text to my healthbar sprite, so that I can easily access it. Also my Phaser version is 2.4.3. I think I should change it.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing now.

Comment: Nope. Even with the latest Phaser version, the error is still there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102082/discussion-between-hristiyan-dodov-and-james-skemp).

Comment: And by the way, that's a nice little game you've got. Minus the minor issues we ran into, it played pretty nicely and looked good.

Comment: Thanks! It's currently a school project, but I'll make it bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the short answer is, you don't want to do what you're doing.

If you want to have access to these you could try doing something like:

```
var statusBarHp = { graphic: '', text: '' };
```

And then setting `statusBarHp.graphic = game.add.sprite(...);` and `statusBarHp.text = game.add.text(...);`.

This might work for easy access to it. However, if you want to act upon both the `Sprite` and `Text` objects using a [`Phaser.Group`](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/category/groups) would be a much better idea.

I might also recommend against using 'text' as the name of the object, since then you run into an oddity with `statusBarHp.text.text = 'new text'`. Your future self might get confused by that, as someone who is fresh to your code (me) was.

As for the error, my guess is that Phaser might be getting confused since you're hijacking the standard Sprite object to add a Text object. JS doesn't care so much and it might work, but again it's a bad practice and there's a better way to handle this.

EDIT:

After chatting and seeing the game in action, I had to disable and then enable the CSS tab in the Firefox Console. (I was expecting errors to be thrown in the standard Console.)

From what I can determine these are warnings, and appear to be an issue with the Phaser framework passing data into Firefox. The framework may be truncating color values to '0' at some point. See https://karinacode.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/expected-color-but-found-0/

My recommendation would be to ignore these. You could also see if someone who has dug deeper into the Phaser framework itself (and perhaps has knowledge about Canvas/WebGL, since it happens with both types of games) can explain why Firefox is throwing this warning.

You could also see what happens if you switched `#000000` to `black` or maybe even `#010101`.